# PostgreSQL encoding issue

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pgadmin

I am running a local postgresql server in version 9.1 and using the postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar for my java application to access the database.

Though i set the encoding to UTF8 and restarted the server, it is not possible to insert (using the application) values with german umlauts like **äöü**. The result looks like this: **√§√∂√º√ü**

I already checked everywhere the encoding and even downgraded the server to version 9.0 with corresponding driver, but nothing helped.

Thanks for helping!
mmm...

Comment: How do you insert these values and check the result?

Comment: Please provide some samples of the code that inserts and the code that read the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. I was working with Mac OSX Lion, and the default system encoding changed to MacRoman after updating. However, changing the encoding fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the text you send to db is also UTF-8 encoded. This means:

- if you have it in a .properties file or something similar make sure that file is UTF-8 encoded (just open it in notepad++ and look what encoding it reports)
- make sure you're compiling your Java code in UTF-8:

  - in in Eclipse, right-click project -> properties -> Resource -> Text File Encoding should be UTF-8
  - if building with Maven, make sure your pom.xml contains:

    ```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    ```
  - if plain-ole command line compiling, do a :

    ```
    javac -encoding UTF-8 *.java
    ```

Comment: Ant encoding is set to ="UTF-8" , eclipse resource property is set to utf-8, test value comes from a java class which is also set to utf-8. Did not help.